# merge multi array to single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array and I would like to merge 1 multidimensional arrays to single array as i desire in output

```
    [087.479.925-22] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [cat] => PRO - ELITE MASCULINO
                    [doc] => 087.479.925-22
                    [etp0] => 613
                    [pto0] => 7
                    [pts] => 26
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [cat] => PRO - ELITE MASCULINO
                    [doc] => 087.479.925-22
                    [etp1] => 620
                    [pto1] => 8
                    [pts] => 26
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [cat] => PRO - ELITE MASCULINO 
                    [doc] => 087.479.925-22
                    [etp2] => 637
                    [pto2] => 11
                    [pts] => 26
                )
        )
```

i would like this output:

```
[087.479.925-22] => Array(
                [cat] => PRO - ELITE MASCULINO
                [doc] => 087.479.925-22
                [etp0] => 613
                [pto0] => 7
                [etp1] => 620
                [pto1] => 8
                [etp2] => 637
                [pto2] => 11
                [pts] => 26
            )
```

Can you help me please, thanks so much

Solution:

```
$result = array_merge(...$array['087.479.925-22']);
```

Comment: What have you tried, where do you fail?

Answer (score 0):

try this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

```php
array_merge_recursive(array ...$arrays): array
```

Comment: But i have only 1 array, and i tried ``` $arrays = array_merge_recursive($array); ```

Comment: You don't need recursive just `$result = array_merge(...$array['087.479.925-22']):`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Tyvm, vc é o cara!